# How to retrieve source code of a model saved with tf.keras.models.save_model()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, editing

I saved a trained model with tf.keras.models.save_model(MyM); it produced a folder with the contents expected. When I retrieve it, using tf.keras.models.load_model(MyM), everything works, except I can’t see the source code.
In sum: what to do if I want to work on the code of a model saved with “save_model”?

Comment: The source code is not saved, its your python files, if you did not save them, they are lost.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Snoopy.  I learnt a hard lesson...